# I am trying to remove the blur effect from my site

Tags: blur

After loading the site creates a blur effect on the thumbnail images on the left side and I am trying to remove this blur effect.

I believe it is part of an javascript, but not sure.

http://www.portlandqueens.com/

How do I prevent the blur effect  from happening to the images?

Comment: I guess before a day or 2, somebody answered on your question that JS was causing this issue, the question itself is pretty vague..

Comment: My primary study is Graphic Design, but am trying to learn the edges of scripting.  Basically, how I diagnose it right now is taking away the code and seeing the result after saving it.  Very primitive, but it tends to find where the code is.

Comment: No, this is the first time I have asked a question on this service.  I have lurked for some time.  Where is the related question that you are referencing?  If there is any help, I would appreciate it as I am learning.